# Why is this no-op loop not optimized away?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

The following code does some copying from one array of zeroes interpreted as floats to another one, and prints timing of this operation. As I've seen many cases where no-op loops are just optimized away by compilers, including gcc, I was waiting that at some point of changing my copy-arrays program it will stop doing the copying.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/time.h>

static inline long double currentTime()
{
    timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    return ts.tv_sec+(long double)(ts.tv_nsec)*1e-9;
}

int main()
{
    size_t W=20000,H=10000;

    float* data1=new float[W*H];
    float* data2=new float[W*H];
    memset(data1,0,W*H*sizeof(float));
    memset(data2,0,W*H*sizeof(float));

    long double time1=currentTime();
    for(int q=0;q<16;++q) // take more time
        for(int k=0;k<W*H;++k)
            data2[k]=data1[k];
    long double time2=currentTime();

    std::cout << (time2-time1)*1e+3 << " ms\n";

    delete[] data1;
    delete[] data2;
}
```

I compiled this with g++ 4.8.1 command `g++ main.cpp -o test -std=c++0x -O3 -lrt`. This program prints `6952.17 ms` for me. (I had to set `ulimit -s 2000000` for it to not crash.)

I also tried changing creation of arrays with `new` to automatic VLAs, removing `memset`s, but this doesn't change g++ behavior (apart from changing timings by several times).

It seems the compiler could prove that this code won't do anything sensible, so why didn't it optimize the loop away?

Comment: It's no op from our perspective, but the compiler do not know and can't known that the content of the memory chunk from data1 and data2 are already equal.

Comment: I can´t give a definite answer, but a) Any optimization is not mandatory. b) You have two `new` but no `delete`.

Comment: @deviantfan I was relying on the memory being freed on exit, although it seems to not be guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Even if major operating systems can do that, it´s just plain wrong to omit delete´s. And, for all i know, that could even solve your optimization problem ("could", not "will").

Comment: @deviantfan I've checked, it doesn't.

Comment: @pan-: it does know, however, that result of data2 calculation is not used. I agree with OP, this kind of code is usually optimized away in my practice and I have to take special steps to make sure it doesn't happen when writing such benchmarks.

Comment: I'm curious to know this. Will you give it a better fighting chance if they aren't dynamic? Odd, ok, but seriously, really curious (I would think it makes no difference, but worth a mod to find out : `static`).

Comment: VLAs? that's not even portable C++.. and keep the original code (too?) it's confusing if the question changes on the fly.

Comment: If you declare W, H as `constexpr` g++ optimizes your code. This, however, is not an answer to your question.

Comment: Why do you keep changing the array allocation? Your current version isn't even zeroing the arrays; it's not a surprise that the compiler doesn't optimize the loop away.

Comment: @user2357112 These were the attempts to simplify the code maximally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyway it isn't impossible (clang++ version 3.3):

```
clang++ main.cpp -o test -std=c++0x -O3 -lrt
```

The program prints 0.000367 ms for me... and looking at the assembly language:

```
...
callq   clock_gettime
movq    56(%rsp), %r14
movq    64(%rsp), %rbx
leaq    56(%rsp), %rsi
movl    $1, %edi
callq   clock_gettime
...
```

while for g++:

```
...
call    clock_gettime
fildq   32(%rsp)
movl    $16, %eax
fildq   40(%rsp)
fmull   .LC0(%rip)
faddp   %st, %st(1)
.p2align 4,,10
.p2align 3
.L2:
 movl    $1, %ecx
 xorl    %edx, %edx
 jmp     .L5
 .p2align 4,,10
 .p2align 3
 .L3:
 movq    %rcx, %rdx
 movq    %rsi, %rcx
 .L5:
 leaq    1(%rcx), %rsi
 movss   0(%rbp,%rdx,4), %xmm0
 movss   %xmm0, (%rbx,%rdx,4)
 cmpq    $200000001, %rsi
 jne     .L3
 subl    $1, %eax
 jne     .L2
 fstpt   16(%rsp)
 leaq    32(%rsp), %rsi
 movl    $1, %edi
 call    clock_gettime
 ...
```

EDIT (g++ v4.8.2 / clang++ v3.3)

SOURCE CODE - ORIGINAL VERSION (1)

```
...
size_t W=20000,H=10000;

float* data1=new float[W*H];
float* data2=new float[W*H];
...
```

SOURCE CODE - MODIFIED VERSION (2)

```
...
const size_t W=20000;
const size_t H=10000;

float data1[W*H];
float data2[W*H];
...
```

Now the case that isn't optimized is (1) + g++

Answer (score 3):

The code in this question has changed quite a bit, invalidating correct answers. This answer applies to the 5th version: as the code currently attempts to read uninitialized memory, an optimizer may reasonably assume that unexpected things are happening.

Many optimization steps have a similar pattern: there's a pattern of instructions that's matched to the current state of compilation. If the pattern matches at some point, the matched pattern is (parametrically) replaced by a more efficient version. A very simple example of such a pattern is the definition of a variable that's not subsequently used; the replacement in this case is simply a deletion.

These patterns are designed for correct code. On incorrect code, the patterns may simply fail to match, or they may match in entirely unintended ways. The first case leads to no optimization, the second case may lead to totally unpredictable results (certainly if the modified code if further optimized)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect the compiler to optimise this? It’s generally really hard to prove that writes to arbitrary memory addresses are a “no-op”. In your case it would be possible, but it would require the compiler to trace the heap memory addresses through `new` (which is once again *hard* since these addresses are generated at runtime) and there really is no incentive for doing this.

After all, you tell the compiler *explicitly* that you want to allocate memory and write to it. How is the poor compiler to know that you’ve been lying to it?

In particular, the problem is that the heap memory could be aliased to lots of other stuff. It happens to be private to your process but like I said above, proving this is a lot of work for the compiler, unlike for function local memory.

Comment: There's no further reference to this memory, that's how.

Comment: I expect the compiler to check the data dependencies and only say "I don't know" about `volatile` memory. Thus it seems quite natural to expect some aggressive enough optimization.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Prove it. Hint: that’s really, really hard.

Comment: in this case, it's really, really simple.

Comment: @MarkusMayr `volatile` also means that any writes to it must be in the prescribed order and count. It may be a pointer to a MMIO region.

Comment: @KonradRudolph anyway, your concerns about new don't seem to be (fully) valid. I've updated the question removing both `memset` and `new` operators.

Comment: @Ruslan I can't believe that it works and does not segfault. The array is waaay to big to be handled on the stack.

Comment: @freakish Yes, `ulimit` is the cure

Comment: @Ruslan Ah, of course. Back to the topic: are you trying to solve a real problem? If not then keep in mind that probably noone will be able to answer that question. Except for people who wrote the compiler. Maybe you should ask them directly?

Comment: @freakish I'm just trying to understand the logic about when to expect some optimizations to ruin the benchmark and when to expect it to work. Now from manlio's answer it appears that clang does optimize this away.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, that's why I said that you should ask people who created g++ ([the mailing list](http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html)). That's not a general problem. The problem is specific to g++. Also I think that you should assume as little as possible about optimizations. Off-topic: clang is a very good compiler, you should try it.

Comment: @freakish maybe good, but not good enough to be able to replace gcc everywhere.

Comment: @Ruslan I’m not convinced that invalidates my answer. It merely shows that *even on the stack* the compiler just doesn’t optimise as far as you think.

Comment: @KonradRudolph of course, I didn't say it must optimize. I was wondering if it must not.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No, that’s simply wrong, unless the compiler treats both `operator new` and `memset` as intrinsics (which it is permitted to do but often doesn’t).

Comment: well, all it has to know is that the memory is not aliased. I would expect that much from the compiler (both for builtin new and memset). After that, it's a simple deduction.

Comment: "After all, you tell the compiler explicitly that you want to allocate memory and write to it. How is the poor compiler to know that you’ve been lying to it?" - just as you *explicitly* tell the compiler to allocate a local variable and write to it. and then never use it again. is that a lie?

Answer (score 0):

The only way in which the compiler could know that this is a no-op is if it knew what `memset` does. In order for that to happen, the function must either be defined in a header (and it typically isn't), or it must be treated as a special intrinsic by the compiler. But barring those tricks, the compiler just sees a call to an unknown function which *could* have side effects and do different things for each of the two calls.

Comment: I'd say the question is not primarily about the `memset`, but about the `data2[k] = data1[k]` loop (since `data2` is no longer accessed after that).

Comment: Commenting `memset` calls out doesn't change behavior (although 6950 ms change to 5500 ms for some reason).

Comment: The same argument holds for `operator new`. And there’s no really any motivation to make memory allocation a compiler intrinsic so the compiler probably doesn’t know about all the intricacies of the operating system’s memory allocation procedure.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: actually, beyond using intrinsics, compilers do cheat. For example in LLVM, `malloc` and `free` (and the mangled names of `new` and `delete`) are known to the optimizer so that if it realizes that the memory is unused (after optimisations for example) then it also optimizes away the allocation/deallocation. This of course violates any implement which would rely on side-effects (and with `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD` they can't know about it), yet it's a strategy used.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Of course they do. I meant that you cannot *expect* them to cheat. I’m slightly surprised that LLVM bothers hooking into `malloc` and `free` but okay.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I am slightly surprised too, I don't know if there is a specific wording in the Standard to allow their elision (like for copy constructors), I've certainly never seen anything mentioned. I also know that LLVM might change a heap-allocation to a stack-allocation as well.